# Deterministic Finite Automata minimization

Tags: automata

If we have a finite automaton with no final/accepting states. So that F is empty. How do you minimize it? 
I got this to a test in which I was asked to minimize an automaton but it had empty F and I didn't know how to approach the problem because the automaton had no accepting states. Is a single initial state with all the transitions into itself the correctly minimized automaton?
I thought that if two automatons A and B for any possible input, A returns the exactly same output as B, they must be equivalent. Thus if an automaton has no final state, then it accepts no input or no input is valid, so it must be equivalent with any other automaton that behaves this way.

Answer (score 1):

If the definition of Finite Automata enforces non empty state set, a single initial state without any transition will do.

Answer (score 0):

Minimization of a finite automata helps in reducing the compile time, as it removes identical operations.

When we minimize an expression,we tend to remove the unused states or we merge two or more states into a single equivalent state which are likely to produce same output. Merging states like this should produce a smaller automaton that accomplishes exactly the same task as our original one. (Here the unreachable states are removed and the states are checked whether they are distinguishable or not. If undistinguishable the states are merged else the states are uniquely represented).

As it reduces the compilation time,results in increasing the processing speed of the program. Running a program which can run a second or two faster than other programs, can vastly increase the scope of the program.